# Unit Of Measures API (JSR-363) - Floating Point Errors

Tags: java, unit-conversion, jsr363

We are using tec.units.unit-ri as an implementation of the JSR-363, javax.measure.unit-api.

We are using several weight-, length- and temperature- types in our application and we decided to use BigDecimal to store them. While doing some conversions, I realized floating point errors were appearing in our instances.

```
Unit<Length> metres = Units.METRE;
Unit<Length> centimetres = Units.METRE.divide(100);
BigDecimal valueInCentimetres = new BigDecimal("10.1");
Quantity<Length> valueInMetres = Quantities.getQuantity(valueInCentimetres, centimetres).to(metres) ;
```

If I run this code, the variable `valueInMetres` contains a `Double` representation with a floating point error, 0.10099999999999999 m. The implementation uses `double` values internally, and loses precision while converting values. We would need to round/introduce a scale to the value, which is not ideal.

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong here? Have I missed some way of using the API which enables me to keep precision, or are all conversions routed over `Double` values and will lose precision, no matter what I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching further after asking this question, I realized that we used the wrong library for our application. [unit-ri](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-ri) is meant for Java ME and uses double internally, [uom-se](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-se) is meant for Java SE and uses BigDecimal. This solves our problem.